# Obtener y Guardar fecha del servidor en Firebase firestore, React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firestore

Buen dia, estoy intentando guardar la fecha del servidor en una colección de firebase pero no tengo idea de como implementarlo en mi código actual:

```
const saveAnswer = (ans) => {
    firestore.collection("userAnswer").doc(dataUser.code).set({
      name: dataUser.name,
      code: dataUser.code,
      question: dataModal.description,
      answerUser: ans,
      answer: dataModal.answer,
      date: ????
    });
    console.log("Agregados los que respondieron");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español! Antes que todo te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), completándolo ganarás tu primera medalla.

Para llevar el control de fechas en JavaScript se utiliza el objeto `Date`, por lo general se recomienda guardar en las bases de datos el tiempo por medio de strings de tipo [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) o por medio de un número que represente el [tiempo Epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) (número de segundos que han ocurrido desde el Epoch) del evento relacionado.

Con la función [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) podemos guardar el tiempo del servidor y podemos usar el mismo objeto de date para convertirlo a una string legible.

```js
//La variable ahora guardará el tiempo en el cuál corres esta script.
//El numero que se guarda en la variable corresponde al tiempo Epoch
const accion = Date.now();

//Para visualizar la hora puedes utilizar el objeto Date
//Entonces creamos un nuevo objeto utilizando como parametro para el constructor el tiempo Epoch
const objectoAccion = new Date(accion);

//Podemos convertirlo en una string  legible para humanos
//utilizando el método .toLocaleString() del objeto Date creado
console.log(objectoAccion.toLocaleString())
```

Para tu implementación tendrías que hacer:

```
const saveAnswer = (ans) => {
    firestore.collection("userAnswer").doc(dataUser.code).set({
      name: dataUser.name,
      code: dataUser.code,
      question: dataModal.description,
      answerUser: ans,
      answer: dataModal.answer,
      date: Date.now()
    });
    console.log("Agregados los que respondieron");
  };
```

Y lo que guardarías en tu base de datos bajo la propiedad `date` es un número en milisegundos que cualquier usuario en el mundo puede convertir a su tiempo local utilizando el método [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).